# Converting a string to int in jxls

Tags: jsp, el, jxls

I am using jxls to display some bean in an Excel worksheet. My bean is called `road`, and I have a property `length` which I want to display, individually and as an aggregate. In my Excel template, I have `${road.length}` inside a `forEach` tag, and then `$[SUM(H3)]`.

My problem is that in the bean, `length` is a String. It is displayed fine in the output Excel, but then the sum is 0.

I got to make it work by using `${road.length - 0}` to force the conversion to int, but I think there must be a more formal solution. Any idea of how to force the conversion in the sum expression?

Answer (score 1):

Even though this question is pretty old, I hope this can help you and others: Try
`${new("java.lang.Integer", road.length)}`

This works with Double, Float, Long, and BigDecimal as well.